# Анимация нажатия назад dialogfragment

Tags: android, анимация, dialogfragment

Есть 3 dialogfragment, которые вызываются по очереди друг из друга.
Нужно сделать анимацию при их переходе так, чтоб они "двигались" справа налево.
Для этого я сделал анимацию, 2 разных

```
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:duration="250"
    />
```

Добавил в стили:

```
  <style name="DialogAnimation" parent="@android:style/Theme.Panel">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/dialogin</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/dialogout</item>
    </style>
```

И добавил в код фрагмента

```
@Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.DialogAnimation;
    }
```

Теперь при переходе между фрагментами анимация работает хорошо.

Как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии кнопки назад анимация шла в обратном порядке?

Answer (score 1):

При создании диалога выполните вот эту команду.

```
MyDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
```

Стиль диалога

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/dialogin</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/dialogout</item>
</style>
```

Comment: так это то же самое что и у меня